# Why isn't call_command( ... stdout=f ) intercepting stdout? At my wits end

Tags: django, django-testing

Help! I am unable to get testing for my management command to work. The command works fine when tested manually:

```
$ ./manage.py import_stock stock/tests/header_only.csv  
Descriptions: 0 found, 0 not found, 0 not unique
StockLines:   0 found, 0 not found, 0 not unique
```

but not in a test. It's outputting to stdout despite [`call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) specifying `stdout=f` (`f` is a `StringIO()`). Running the test, I get

```
$ ./manage.py  test stock/tests --keepdb
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Descriptions: 0 found, 0 not found, 0 not unique
StockLines:   0 found, 0 not found, 0 not unique
Returned
""

F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_001_invocation (test_import_stock_mgmt_cmd.Test_010_import_stock)
make sure I've got the basic testing framework right!
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nigel/django/sarah/silsondb/stock/tests/test_import_stock_mgmt_cmd.py",line 32, in test_001_invocation
    self.assertIn('Descriptions: 0', text)                     # do-nothing
AssertionError: 'Descriptions: 0' not found in ''

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.006s

FAILED (failures=1)
Preserving test database for alias 'default'...
```

The test code which generates this is as follows. `print(f'Returned\n"{text}"')` shows that I'm getting a null string back from `do_command` (which creates the StringIO() and invokes `call_command` ). What I'm trying to intercept is being written to the console, just as when I invoke the command directly.

```
import csv
import io

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.management.base import CommandError
from django.test import TestCase

class Test_010_import_stock( TestCase):

    def do_command( self, *args, **kwargs):
        with io.StringIO() as f:
            call_command(  *args, stdout=f ) 
            return f.getvalue()

    def test_001_invocation(self):
        """ make sure I've got the basic testing framework right! """

        text = self.do_command( 'import_stock', 'stock/tests/header_only.csv')
        print(f'Returned\n"{text}"')
        print()
        self.assertIn('Descriptions: 0', text)                     # do-nothing
        self.assertIn('Stocklines:   0', text )
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering own question. It was a silly bit of confusion in the management command itself.

I *knew* you didn't use `print` but should use `self.stdout.write()` in a management command

But a braino resulted in `sys.stdout.write` and by sheer bad luck, this particular command was importing sys. It's been one of those mornings.